# Rspec - expect to receive only if method exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In rspec, you can use an instance_double to ensure that your expectations are valid - in other words, if I have:

```
class Foo
  def bar
  end
end
```

I can do

```
dbl = instance_double('Foo')
expect(dbl).to receive(:bar)
...
```

and I know that if I remove the `bar` method from `Foo`, my test will throw an error, preventing me from silently breaking things.

**How can I achieve this same effect with class methods?** I just accidentally caused a bug which my tests didn't catch, because I did the following:

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
  end
end
```

Test:

```
expect(Foo).to receive(:baz)
Foo.baz
```

No errors were raised because I added a stub via the above expectation, but really that method doesn't exist. I'm aware I could do `class_double`, but `Foo.baz` is called in another part of my code, not in my test, so I can't get it to call the `class_double` instead of the actual class.

Comment: Why mock it in the first place? `expect(Foo).to respond_to(:bar)`

Comment: i'm not testing if it responds to bar, i'm testing that it is called by some other code

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is turn on partial double verification:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
end
```

This will cause partial doubles to have the same behaviour as doubles created via `object_double`.